# how to find counterfeit coin out of 8 coins

Tags: algorithm

3 Suppose there are seven coins, all with the same weight, and a counterfeit coin that weights less than the others. How many weighings are necessary using a balance scale to determine which of the eight coins is the counterfeit one? Give an algorithm for finding this counterfeit coin.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming-related.

Comment: What have you tried? It's a very popular puzzle. I recommend think about it for a while, than ask google, I You cannot figure it out. (3 weightings are sufficient)

Comment: @MrSmith42 I would go with 2 ;)

Comment: @Nico Schertler: You are right. How could I miss that ;-)

Comment: Solution can be found here: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/EightCoins.shtml#solution

Answer (score 1):

Two weighings will suffice – compare coins 1,2,3 to 4,5,6 first, then you'll have two or three coins for the second comparision.